# Alpine image error finding repository/packages while running docker build on local machine

Tags: dockerfile, docker-build, alpine-package-keeper

I have a Dockerfile that builds and runs successfully in Azure pipelines (using docker build task)

When I try to run docker build on my local machine with the same file, apk add [package name] fails, seemingly with an issue finding the alpine repository.

```
 => ERROR [backend-server 3/4] RUN apk add --no-cache       chromium       nss       freetype       freetype-dev       harfbuzz         11.4s
------
 > [backend-server 3/4] RUN apk add --no-cache       chromium       nss       freetype       freetype-dev       harfbuzz       ca-certificates       ttf-freefont       nodejs       npm:
#6 0.410 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#6 5.416 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#6 5.416 WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main: temporary error (try again later)
#6 10.42 WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community: temporary error (try again later)
#6 10.42 ERROR: unable to select packages:
#6 10.42   ca-certificates (no such package):
#6 10.42     required by: world[ca-certificates]

...
```

The dockerfile uses node:16.13.0-apline3.14

```
FROM node:16.13.0-alpine3.14 AS build

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . ./

RUN npm i
RUN npm run build 

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/dist

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm ci

FROM node:16.13.0-alpine3.14 AS backend-server

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN apk add --no-cache \
      chromium \
      nss \
      freetype \
      freetype-dev \
      harfbuzz \
      ca-certificates \
      ttf-freefont \
      nodejs \
      npm
```

I've tried fetching fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz and the file exists and downloads correctly on my actual computer. I've also tried running by setting the repository (adding apk add -X https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main), and setting --allow-untrusted, both with exact same results.

The logs in the pipeline show the fetch succeed.

```
Step 58/72 : RUN apk add --no-cache       chromium       nss       freetype       freetype-dev       harfbuzz       ca-certificates       ttf-freefont       nodejs       npm
 ---> Running in xxxxxxxxx
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/122) Upgrading zlib (1.2.11-r3 -> 1.2.12-r3)
(2/122) Installing ca-certificates (20220614-r0)
```

What are other possible causes of this issue, and why would it be different than running in an azure pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably an issue with your docker desktop's network configuration. You may need to do a clean reinstall of docker desktop to fix the issue.